# Unwind array and return the last element matching condition

Tags: c#, mongodb

Say I have a document structure that looks like

```
[
    { 
        _id:1,
        Logs : [
            { time: 123, x: 24 },
            { time: 212, x: 13 },
            { time: 325, x: 34 }
        ]
    },
    { 
        _id:2,
        Logs : [
            { time: 63, x: 19 },
            { time: 112, x: 25 },
            { time: 205, x: 15 }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to get is the value of `x` where `time` < n and _id = y

So for example, where if y=2, and n=115 i would want 25 return.

Given that `time` < 115 and the greatest time matching the filter in the array?

I'm going this in C#, but could convert from shell syntax if anyone can help?

thanks

EDIT:

So the question I'm asking is... $elemmatch will only return the document if it finds one match, so $elemmatch on time<115 and _id=2 would return the second document.  if I project the array, i will get all three Logs sub docs.

I'm therefore assuming I need to use Aggregation to filter the projected array?

Comment: So what's the problem that you're having?  What are you doing now, and why isn't it working?

Comment: does it make more sense now?

Comment: So what's the code that you're using that has the problems you've described?

Comment: @Servy it was a question based on the examples i posted.  if it wasn't clear enough for you - i'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregation will get you the desired results:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     "$match": {"_id": y, "Logs.time": {"$lt": n} }
   },
   {
     "$unwind": "$Logs"
   }, 
   {
     "$match": {"Logs.time": {"$lt": n} }
   },
   {
     "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "x": { "$max": "$Logs.x"  }
     }
   },
   {
     "$project": {
         "_id": 0,
         "x": 1
     }
   }
])
```

Comment: great, thats what i needed. ive changed a little to sort asc the projected results and limited to 1. i now have a problem with c# v2 driver and unwind that i'll post on separately

Comment: @sambomartin Nice one hey, I barely thought of the **`$sort`** and **`$limit`** option :P